# create mail with script bridge

Tags: cocoa, email, scripting-bridge

I am trying to create a new email using the cocoa scripting bridge,but can not seem to get it to work.I have so far:

```
MailApplication *mail = [SBApplication applicationWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.apple.Mail"];
MailOutgoingMessage *emailMessage = [[[[mail classForScriptingClass:@"outgoing message"]     alloc] initWithProperties:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [saveFileName substringToIndex:[saveFileName length]-4], @"subject", @"something about app.", @"content", nil]] autorelease];
// add the object to the mail app 
[[mail outgoingMessages] addObject: emailMessage];
emailMessage.visible = YES;

if ( [FileFullName length] > 0 ) {

    MailAttachment *theAttachment = 
    [[[mail classForScriptingClass:@"attachment"] alloc]
     initWithProperties:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                         FileFullName, @"fileName",nil]];
    // add it to the list of attachments 
    [[emailMessage.content attachments] addObject: theAttachment];
    [theAttachment release];
}
```

When I try and set the visible property,I got the error message:

```
-[SBProxyByClass setVisible:]: object has not been added to a container yet; selector not recognized [self = 0x7fd4fae3cc90]
```

This issue appeared when I added the sandbox for app.
Can anyone point the correct direction?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your code can work before you enable the sandbox, then you should do this first before you send the mail. Add the follow code to your Entitlements.plist.

```
    <key>com.apple.security.temporary-exception.apple-events</key>
    <array>
    <string>com.apple.mail</string>
    </array>
```